# How much was BAT (Basic Attention Token) worth in eth / btc / usd during the 1 minute ICO?

Tags: tokens, ico, basic-attention-token

What was the value of BAT (Basic Attention Token) during the 1 minute ICO in eth / usd / btc ? I can't seem to find this info anywhere. And what is the total supply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.basicattentiontoken.org/faq/#price

> The ICO price on the sale date of May 31, 2017 was 1 ETH to 6,400 BAT.
>
> We sold the equivalent of 156,250 ETH, or 1 billion tokens.

Comment: what is that in Bitcoin price at that time? and today?

Comment: @duckx - easier done than said - this is the first search result for `historical ether price` - https://etherscan.io/chart/etherprice

Answer (score 0):

According to https://icostats.com/, the ICO price was $0.035usd per BAT token, which would have given you (according to https://ethereumprice.org/ the price of 1ETH was $288.65 on May 31st) 8247 BAT per 1ETH

Using etherscan.io, we can see the total supply on the [token page](https://etherscan.io/token/BAT) as 1,500,000,000 BAT.

If you [read the contract](https://etherscan.io/token/BAT#readContract), you can see `totalSupply = 1500000000000000000000000000 uint256`, which is a wei measurement that translates to 1500000000.